# iOS Simulator App Location

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am running OS X El Capitan which has iOS Simulator 9.2 installed.

I am **NOT** looking for the xCode install directory. I am looking for the folder where all of the Simulator default apps are installed. Can someone please direct me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/Applications
```

Contains:

```
AACredentialRecoveryDialog.app
AccountAuthenticationDialog.app
AdSheet.app
Camera.app
Contacts.app
CoreAuthUI.app
DDActionsService.app
DataActivation.app
FacebookAccountMigrationDialog.app
Game Center.app
GameCenterUIService.app
Health.app
HealthPrivacyService.app
HomeUIService.app
MailCompositionService.app
Maps.app
MessagesViewService.app
MobileCal.app
MobileSafari.app
MobileSlideShow.app
MusicUIService.app
News.app
Passbook.app
PassbookUIService.app
PhotosViewService.app
Preferences.app
Print Center.app
Reminders.app
SLGoogleAuth.app
SLYahooAuth.app
SafariViewService.app
ServerDocuments.app
ShareBear.app
SharedWebCredentialViewService.app
SocialUIService.app
StoreKitUIService.app
TencentWeiboAccountMigrationDialog.app
TrustMe.app
WatchKitSettings.app
Web.app
WebApp1.app
WebContentAnalysisUI.app
WebSheet.app
WebViewService.app
iAdOptOut.app
iCloudDriveApp.app
quicklookd.app
```

Comment: Sir! You are a gentleman and a scholar. I thank you kindly :) They changed the location on me in an update and i was pulling my hair out looking for it haha

Answer (score 0):

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Applications/