# iOS 11 Simulator native apps location

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I'm using Xcode 9 and would like to find where are located the native iOS apps (Contacts, Maps, Photos, News, etc) that run inside the Simulator.

According to the answer at [iOS Simulator App Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35926552/ios-simulator-app-location/), they used to be at

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/Applications
```

but this is not the case anymore.

Any ideas where I can find them now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode 9, they are now located here:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Applications
```

The applications in this folder are the following:

- AccountAuthenticationDialog
- ActivityMessagesApp
- AdSheet
- AirMusic
- AirPodcasts
- AppStore
- AskPermissionUI
- Bridge
- BusinessExtensionsWrapper
- Calculator
- Camera
- ChargingViewService
- CheckerBoard
- Contacts
- CoreAuthUI
- CTCarrierSpaceAuth
- DataActivation
- DDActionsService
- Diagnostics
- DiagnosticsService
- DNDBuddy
- FaceTime
- Family
- Feedback Assistant iOS
- Files
- FindMyFriends
- Fitness
- Game Center UI Service
- HashtagImages
- Health
- HealthPrivacyService
- HomeUIService
- iAdOptOut
- iBooks
- iCloud
- iTunes
- Jellyfish
- LoginUI
- Magnifier
- MailCompositionService
- Maps
- MessagesViewService
- MobileCal
- MobileMail
- MobileNotes
- MobileSafari
- MobileSlideShow
- MobileSMS
- Music
- MusicUIService
- News
- Passbook
- PassbookUIService
- Photo Booth
- PhotosViewService
- Podcasts
- PreBoard
- Preferences
- Print Center
- Reminders
- SafariViewService
- ScreenSharingViewService
- ScreenshotServicesService
- ServerDocuments
- SharedWebCredentialViewService
- SharingViewService
- Siri
- SLGoogleAuth
- SLYahooAuth
- SoftwareUpdateUIService
- StoreDemoViewService
- TrustMe
- TV
- Videos
- VideoSubscriberAccountViewService
- Web
- WebApp1
- WebContentAnalysisUI
- WebSheet
- WLAccessService

Comment: Thanks! It's interesting that when checking the contents of some of them they don't contain the app icons (e.g., Contacts.app). So where the Simulator gets the icons from?